# .net core model binding standard different from .net 4.6

Tags: asp.net-core, model-binding

After migrated from .net 4.6 to .net core 1.1, the Model Binding acceptance is quite different as below:

- For .net 4.6, the model binding work by accepting request parameters (query string) as below

  Boundary[TopLeft][Lat]:10.808969811804062
  Boundary[TopLeft][Lon]:106.63826676953124
  Boundary[BottomRight][Lat]:10.785699937603939
  Boundary[BottomRight][Lon]:106.72066423046874
  Center[lat]:10.7973351
  Center[lon]:106.6794655
  Limit:1000
- For .net core 1.1, the model binding work by accepting request parameters (query string) as below

  Boundary.TopLeft.Lat:10.808969811804062
  Boundary.TopLeft.Lon:106.63826676953124
  Boundary.BottomRight.Lat:10.785699937603939
  Boundary.BottomRight.Lon:106.72066423046874
  Center.lat:10.7973351
  Center.lon:106.6794655
  Limit:1000

Because of that, all the query from the client failed (model binding shows empty object). Is there any configuration of .net core to accept Boundary[TopLeft][Lat] instead of Boundary.TopLeft.Lat?

Comment: To be more precise, I used jQuery to perform an ajax request (GET/POST) to query users in boundary, jQuery parsed requested data as Boundary[TopLeft][Lat] which has no problem at all with .net 4.6 API. However, .net core 1.1 requires the format as Boundary.TopLeft.Lat or else it will not readable.

Answer (score 0):

Found a cool library from npm which is "[qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs)", it could stringify data with "allowDots" option set to "true". Then, it will parse the object into Boundary.Top.Left instead of Boundary[Top][Left]